# How to remove an extra keyboard layout that is not in the control panel option?

Tags: keyboard-layout, windows-server-2008-r2, control-panel

My keyboard setting have only 1 language in, but windows still keep another keyboard layout that I can't remove from the language input bar.

It can be seen here :

[image: keyboard issue]

It's really annoying because it seems that "Canadien multilingue standard" is the default layout, so whenever I open something, the keyboard layout change to that.

(Windows 2008 R2 Standard)

Comment: My French is too bad to help you in answer, but you need to go to the second or third tab on that screen, look about halfway down the page, and check "disable advanced text services" or equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Try to switch keyboard layout to `"Not Assigned".`

[image: Change Key Sequence]

Most likely keyboard layout icon will disappear. There is a difference between Language and Layout. So 2 different "switchers" can be displayed in system tray at the same time (one as EN or FR and one as keyboard icon). On first your image you can see Language settings, but on second you try to select keyboard Layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add another input language and then make it default (for example, English).
Then go to `Installed Services` section of the window select French language - delete it.
Then add it again and set as a default.